# wso2 identity server axisfualt message when connecting to entitlement service

Tags: wso2, apache-axis, identity, wso2-identity-server

I have been following the blog at http://hasini-gunasinghe.blogspot.com/2011/12/entitlement-service-xacml-pdp-as-web.html but I cannot connect to identity server, every time I try I get the following error:

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
        at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter.writeTo(SOAPMessageFormatter.java:78)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisRequestEntity.writeRequest(AxisRequestEntity.java:84)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.writeRequestBody(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:499)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2114)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender.executeMethod(AbstractHTTPSender.java:621)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:193)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:75)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:449)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:276)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:443)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:406)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
        at org.wso2.carbon.authenticator.stub.AuthenticationAdminStub.login(AuthenticationAdminStub.java:659)
        at EntitlementClient.login(EntitlementClient.java:109)
        at EntitlementClient.main(EntitlementClient.java:79)
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter m
ust be non-empty
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.finishDocument(BaseStreamWriter.java:1692)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.close(BaseStreamWriter.java:288)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamWriterWrapper.close(XMLStreamWriterWrapper.java:46)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.MTOMXMLStreamWriter.close(MTOMXMLStreamWriter.java:188)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.serializeAndConsume(OMSerializableImpl.java:197)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter.writeTo(SOAPMessageFormatter.java:74)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be
 non-empty
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkEOF(SSLSocketImpl.java:1293)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkWrite(SSLSocketImpl.java:1305)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:43)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
        at java.io.FilterOutputStream.flush(FilterOutputStream.java:123)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.ChunkedOutputStream.flush(ChunkedOutputStream.java:191)
        at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Writer.flush(UTF8Writer.java:99)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.flush(BufferingXmlWriter.java:214)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.close(BufferingXmlWriter.java:194)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.finishDocument(BaseStreamWriter.java:1690)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:190)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1649)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1612)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1595)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1521)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:64)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
        at java.io.FilterOutputStream.flush(FilterOutputStream.java:123)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.ChunkedOutputStream.flush(ChunkedOutputStream.java:191)
        at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Writer.flush(UTF8Writer.java:99)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.flush(BufferingXmlWriter.java:214)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.flush(BaseStreamWriter.java:311)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamWriterWrapper.flush(XMLStreamWriterWrapper.java:50)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.MTOMXMLStreamWriter.flush(MTOMXMLStreamWriter.java:198)
        at org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBDataSource.serialize(ADBDataSource.java:91)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:691)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.util.OMSerializerUtil.serializeChildren(OMSerializerUtil.java:563)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMElementImpl.java:875)
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPEnvelopeImpl.serializeInternally(SOAPEnvelopeImpl.java:283)
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPEnvelopeImpl.internalSerialize(SOAPEnvelopeImpl.java:245)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.serializeAndConsume(OMSerializableImpl.java:193)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.<init>(PKIXValidator.java:57)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.getInstance(Validator.java:161)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.getValidator(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:108)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:204)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:249)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1185)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:136)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:593)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:529)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:893)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1138)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:632)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:59)
        ... 36 more
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
        at java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.setTrustAnchors(PKIXParameters.java:183)
        at java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.<init>(PKIXParameters.java:103)
        at java.security.cert.PKIXBuilderParameters.<init>(PKIXBuilderParameters.java:87)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.<init>(PKIXValidator.java:55)
        ... 48 more
```

I do not know why this keeps coming up, one minute everything is fine and the next I get this.  Please help, am trying to get into using wso2 products but the lack of support is making a difficult task

Comment: WSO2 Identity Server 4.0.0 is released today. You can download it from http://wso2.com/products/identity-server/, could you please try and see whether you still get the issue.

Comment: I have installed Identity server 4.0.0 and I still get the same error.  I do not understand, I was not getting this error a week ago, now all of a sudden I can not do anything, Please point me in the write direction, am desperate

Comment: no I am not using OpenJDK, why do you ask?

Answer (score 0):

Please add below code in your class. It works fine for me. double backslash is important in below addressing.

```
private AuthenticationAdminStub authstub = null;
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","C:\\Tools\\wso2is-5.1.0\\wso2is-5.1.0\\repository\\resources\\security\\wso2carbon.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "wso2carbon");
boolean loggedIn = authstub.login("admin", "admin", "localhost");
```