# WSO2 Identity Server - First Access to Entitlement Menu for PAP and PDP Throws Error

Tags: wso2, axis, identity

At the first access to the Main - Entitlement - Policy section I get the following error:

> TID[-1234] [IS] [2015-05-07 11:11:03,046] ERROR
>   {org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver} - Exception
>   occurred while trying to invoke service method getAllPolicies
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
>   org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
>   org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
>   org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
>   org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
>   org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:169)
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:82)
>   org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.local.CarbonLocalTransportSender.finalizeSendWithToAddress(CarbonLocalTransportSender.java:45)
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportSender.invoke(LocalTransportSender.java:77)
>   org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
>   org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:430)
>   org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
>   org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)

Similar to report: [see at this forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202060/wso2-identity-server-axisfualt-message-when-connecting-to-entitlement-service/)

Thanks in advance for assistance how fix this error.

Comment: Dear colleagues, 

 I appreciate any feedback that helps to correct the WSO2 setup options and fix this error.
  
 My guess it somehow relate to to fact that the server runs on a virtual hosting resource, using a predefined host name and IP address, what make it difficult to use the default localhost based addressing.  Is there any entitlement permission or further XML set-up adjustment required 
to support the administrator access to the Entitlement (XACML) rules set: 

Error:

Comment: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method getAllPolicies 

Thanks in advance for support.